# Taking derivative of an integral involving an indicator function

Tags: integration, derivatives, dirac-delta

Edit: I realized this problem might be better solved as 'derivative of integral with variable in bounds and integrand', e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223409/how-to-find-the-derivative-of-an-integral-where-both-the-limit-and-the-integran).

I'm trying to take the derivative of a double integral, and the variable to be differentiated is inside the integral limits, so I use the indicator function to move the variable $a$ to the integrand. The original integral is
$$
\frac{d}{da} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-a-z}^{a-z} b^2 f(b) g(z) db dz.
$$
Use the indicator function for the integration limits $b \in [-a-z, a-z]$, the integral becomes
$$
\frac{d}{da} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 1\{ -a \leq b+z \leq a \} f(b) g(z) db dz,
$$
where $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to (0, +\infty)$ and their form unknown, and $b^2 f(b) g(z)>0$ for any $(b,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} $. What I tried is below, taking derivative of the indicator function inside the integral:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 \frac{d}{da} [ 1\{ a \geq -(b+z) \} \cdot 1\{ b+z \leq a \} ] f(b) g(z) db dz \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 \frac{d}{da} [ 1\{ a \geq -(b+z) \} ] \cdot 1\{ b+z \leq a \} f(b) g(z) db dz \\
&+ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 1\{ a \geq -(b+z) \} \cdot \frac{d}{da} [ 1\{ b+z \leq a \}] f(b) g(z) db dz \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2  \delta(-(b+z)-a) \cdot 1\{ a \geq b+z \} f(b) g(z) db dz \\
&+ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 1\{ a \geq -(b+z) \} \cdot \delta((b+z)-a) f(b) g(z) db dz,
\end{split}
\end{align}
and $\delta(\cdot)$ is the dirac measure. So $\delta(-(b+z)-a) =1$ if and only if $-(b+z)-a=0$, if and only if $a = -(b+z)$, which means $1\{ a \geq b+z \} = 1\{ -(b+z) \geq b+z \} = 1\{ b+z\leq0 \}$. Similarly $\delta((b+z)-a) =1$ if and only if $a=b+z$, which means $1\{ a \geq -(b+z) \} = 1\{ b+z \geq -(b+z) \} = 1\{b+z \geq0 \}$. Plug into the integral, get
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2  1\{ b+z\leq0 \} f(b) g(z) db dz + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 1\{b+z \geq0 \} f(b) g(z) db dz\\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} b^2 f(b) g(z) db dz,
\end{split}
\end{align}
which is obviously wrong. I have trouble identifying the mistake. For the derivative of the indicator function, I used this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484849/differentiating-indicator-function) and
$$
\frac{d}{da} 1\{ a \geq b+z \} = \frac{d}{da} [1 - 1\{ a \leq b+z \}]
= -(-\delta(a-(b+z))) = \delta(a-(b+z)) = \delta((b+z)-a),
$$
and the last equality is because 'symmetry' of dirac measure.
Can anyone take a look and point out my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: If the integrand is identically zero for $b$ outside of the interval indicated by the indicator function, then just set the bounds of the inner integral to that interval, surely. I don't see any need to invoke the delta distribution or distributional derivatives when this problem can be approached through elementary means, and you would necessarily need to invoke distributions to differentiate an indicator function since they are not differentiable in a conventional sense.

Comment: Hi Jam, the integrand is not identically zero outside of $\{(b,z): -a \leq b+z \leq a \}$, and I'm hoping to take derivative like this because the form of $f,g$ is unspecified (other than they are probability density functions with support on the real line).

Comment: In that case, could you describe how the indicator function would be evaluated for $b$ outside of $[-z-a,-z+a]$? Ordinarily an indicator function evaluates to zero outside of its indicated subset, so I would expect that to zero out the whole integrand.

Comment: @Jam Sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated my post: the variable to be differentiate is originally inside the integral limits, so I used the indicator function to move this variable into the integrand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid the indicator function entirely, since such expressions tend to be awkward to work with due to their limited algebraic properties. Instead, tackle the problem using the first expression for the integral. Take the $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}$ sign under the integral signs using two applications of the Leibniz integral rule, and factor out the $g(z)$ term from the inner integral since it is independent of the variable being integrated against, $b$. This leaves you with a single integral of an expression in $f, g$, which will definitely not have a general closed form. So that will be the most general solution you can hope for, without knowing more about the particular properties of $f,g$.

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-a-z}^{a-z} b^2 f(b) g(z) \,\mathrm{d}b \,\mathrm{d}z
\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(z)\int_{-a-z}^{a-z} b^2 f(b)  \,\mathrm{d}b \,\mathrm{d}z
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(z)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_{-a-z}^{a-z} b^2 f(b)  \,\mathrm{d}b \,\mathrm{d}z
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(z)\left((a-z)'(a-z)^2 f(a-z) -(-a-z)'(-a-z)^2 f(-a-z) -\int 0\right) \,\mathrm{d}z
\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(z)\left[(a-z)^2 f(a-z) +(-a-z)^2 f(-a-z)\right]\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}$$

As a general word of advice, I'd avoid attempting to solve problems by reframing them in terms of the unwieldy sorts of functions associated with discontinuous, chopped-up ranges, including $1(\cdot),\operatorname{sign}(\cdot),|\cdot|,\lfloor\cdot\rfloor,\lceil\cdot\rceil, \max(),\min()$, and so on. They have very few useful algebraic properties, and unless your problem actually involved them to begin with, I don't think they tend to help. For instance, by virtue of their abundant useful properties, it's straightforward to integrate a polynomial, such as $\int (x^2-2x-1) \,\mathrm{d}x=\frac13x^3-x^2-x+C$, but doing so with the sign value of the same expression requires some awkward evaluations of conditions $\int \operatorname{sign}(x^2-2x-1) \,\mathrm{d}x=\begin{cases}x+C_1,&x<-(\sqrt{2}-1)\\-x+C_2,&-(\sqrt{2}-1)<x<(\sqrt{2}+1)\\\ldots\end{cases}$

And I'd also suggest avoiding using overpowered methods where elementary ones are sufficient, such as using the theory of distributions on an elementary integral of real-valued functions. We call this approach "using a sledgehammer to crack a nut". See [MSE Q798215](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798215/nuking-the-mosquito-ridiculously-complicated-ways-to-achieve-very-simple-resul). It is generally considered inelegant as it tends to skip all the logical directness and intuition that the elementary proof should have been providing. It's like using a Rube Goldberg machine to achieve something that could have been done directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I worked out the same answer using the post in my edit. I will try avoiding derivative of indicator function / min / max / absolute value, etc.